# DNS-сервер на Windows

Tags: windows, dns, сервер

Скажите, пожалуйста, если на `windows server`'е поставить `dns` сервер, то там можно будет зарегистрировать свой домен?

Comment: Домен можно зарегистрировать у регистратора доменов

Comment: Да это я знаю я хотел у себя на сервере бесплатно

Comment: Можно, только mydomen.ru будут видеть только те, у кого в настройках сети пропишешь DNS-ками свой сервер.

Comment: Ясно мне это не подходит

Comment: Не по теме конечно, но я удивляюсь )) Людям жалко 150 рублей в год за домен))

Comment: нет 95 рублей жалко

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Регистрация доменов никак не связана с вашим DNS сервером. Он необходим для обслуживания уже зарегистрированного доменного имени.

- [Регистрация доменов](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регистрация_доменов)
- [Регистратор доменных имён](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регистратор_доменных_имён)

Comment: то есть бесплатно никак да

Comment: Ты какой домен хочешь, если localhost или что то типа того то пожалуйста, регистрируй на своем сервере.

Comment: нет я хотел что то типо mydomen.ru